# Specify CIFS vs NFS for UNC in Windows?

Tags: windows, nfs, unc, cifs

On Windows 2008 Server R2 (acting as a client) I have the Client from Windows Services for NFS installed and a server mounted as Y: with NFS.  That server also supports CIFS.  When I open a UNC path to the server with start/run it connects using CIFS but when an application on the same client is passed the same UNC path it connects using NFS.  The full UNC path (not the Y: drive letter) is used in both cases.

How does Windows determine whether to use NFS or CIFS when passed a UNC path?